# Can Sonar Scan be triggered as part of regular maven Build command like " mvn build"?

Tags: maven, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan, sonar-maven-plugin

Im looking to see any maven configuration which will enable me to run Sonar Scan on my code for every maven build. I dont want to use a separate goal but somehow enforce it as part of users regular build commands.

Comment: What is the problem with using it as a goal? The analysis is done by your CI?

Comment: The goal is to enforce sonar scan for developers in an organization in their local development , sort of while they are still doing regular maven builds locally. We would like them to see the Sonar warnings. The idea is to integrate SOnar at multiple levels , at IDE level or command line, commit time and then build time.

Answer (score 1):

You can attach Sonar to a phase (e.g. verify) like this:

```
<plugin>
   <groupId>org.sonarsource.scanner.maven</groupId>
   <artifactId>sonar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
   <version>3.5.0.1254</version>
   <executions>
       <execution>
          <id>verify-sonar</id>
          <phase>verify</phase>
          <goals>
             <goal>sonar</goal>
          </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

This also works with other phases like compile or package.

Comment: Where should i put the properties like specifiying sonarqube server url and username/password and token?

Comment: <plugin>
      <groupId>org.sonarsource.scanner.maven</groupId>
      <artifactId>sonar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>3.6.0.1746</version>
      <properties>
        <sonar.host.url>
              http://sonarurl.com:9000
        </sonar.host.url>
        <sonar.projectKey>
           MyProj
        </sonar.projectKey>
        <sonar.login>
            myuser
        </sonar.login>
        <sonar.password>
            myuserpass
        </sonar.password>
      </properties>
      <executions>
     .....
      </executions>
</plugin>

Comment: Hi @sunnyX, just put them as global properties as described here: https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/analysis/scan/sonarscanner-for-maven/

Comment: I have updated the properties in the settings, even updated the project Key.

Comment: And you're still unable to run the sonar analysis? Is your initital problem (attaching the scan to a maven goal) fixed? I'm sorry, I'm getting a bit confused ;-)